# get_user_meta() doesn't include user email?

Tags: users, email, user-meta

I simply wonder why `<?php var_dump(get_user_meta(4)); ?>` doesn't contain an email address of the user. Instead I have to use

`get_userdata(4)->user_email;` to query the email of the user.

Why is that or did I miss something? `get_user_meta()` seems to provide all other aspects and informations of a user, however just not the email-address.

Matt

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`get_user_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/) retrieves a single meta field or all fields of the `user_meta` data for the given user.

This means that all the values that are stored in `user_meta` table can be got using [`get_user_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/).  Email is not stored as meta data so you cant get email using [`get_user_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/).

Email is stored with username and password in `user` table as user data.

Comment: Um, so how do we get the user email to store as a variable?

Comment: @Osu see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo  ,http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata

Answer (score 14):

Just wanted to let you know you have `get_user_meta` and `get_userdata`. The email address can be found using the `get_userdata` function.

For the current user this code can apply:

```
<?php

  $user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
  $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
  $mailadresje = $user_info->user_email;
  echo $mailadresje;

?>
```

Please note this is applicable to the current user. If you need to get the `user_id` of let's say an order you need the following code (which I used to display the users mail on the invoice in WooCommerce) :

```
<?php

  $user_id = $wpo_wcpdf->export->order->user_id;
  $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
  $mailadresje = $user_info->user_email;
  echo $mailadresje;

?>
```

Happy programming!

Comment: Thanks you, fellow countryman :)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to just return the user email from a user id and not load the entire user object, here is a quick function which utilizes the $wpdb global variable:

```
function get_user_email($user_id){
  global $wpdb;
  return $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_email FROM wp_users WHERE id=%d", $user_id));
}
```

Comment: Is that actually more efficient? I'd guess the other way is still only one database read, and might be in the request's in-memory cache too.

Comment: Yes it's more efficient. get_userdata() will trigger update_meta_cache() which queries the user's meta data within the wp_usermeta table.

Comment: OK, fair enough. `WP_User::get_data_by( 'id', $user_id )` then, which does the cache but not the meta etc.